# Auto refresh table without refreshing page PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, chat, reload

I have a very simple chat system I've built using PHP and MySQL (this is my second day ever using these languages) and I am wondering if there is any way to auto refresh the table data I'm pulling from my database and loading into an html table via PHP without having something like Javascript go and reload the whole web page... just reloading the html table with the data in it that PHP filled it up with.... Does that make sense?

Here is my code if it helps (for /chat.php)

```
<html><head></head><body><center>
<form action="chat.php" method="post">
Message: <br><textarea type="text" name="message" style="width:80%; height:300px;"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton"/> <a href="http://www.****.com/chat.php"><button name="Refresh Chat">Refresh Chat</button></a>
</form>
<div style="width:100%;">

<?php

$host="****";
$user="****";
$password="****";

$cxn = mysql_pconnect ($host, $user, $password);

mysql_select_db("defaultdb", $cxn);

if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) {
    $ipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
} else {
    $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
}

$message = nl2br(strip_tags(nl2br($_POST["message"])));

if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) { 
    if ($message != "") {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO ChatTest (ID, TimeStamp, Message) VALUES ('$ipaddress', NOW(), '$message')");
    }
    header('Location: chat.php');
}

$message = "";

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ChatTest ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3 width='100%' style='table-layout:fixed'>
        "; 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th style='width:10%;'>ID:</th><th style='width:10%;'>TimeStamp:</th><th style='width:70%;'>Message:</th>";
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
 Print "
        <tr>"; 
    Print " <td>".$info['ID'] . "</td> "; 
    Print " <td>".$info['TimeStamp'] . " </td>";
    Print " <td style='white-space:pre-wrap;white-space:-moz-pre-wrap;white-space:-pre-wrap;white-space:-o-pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word'>".$info['Message'] . "</td></tr>
            "; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 

mysql_close($cxn);


?>

</div></center></body></html>
```

Comment: PHP is just server-side, so you'll need something like Javascript to run the PHP script and re-populate the table. You can use Jquery's $.ajax function to populate a certain bit of content I.E. Just the DIV in this instance - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The technique is called AJAX and one of the easiest libraries to add to the project would be [jQuery](http://jquery.com). I assume your issue isn't with JavaScript, but with the idea of reloading the entire page.

**UPDATE**
Because I'm such a nice guy ;) This should work, more or less, I haven't tried it out, so there might be a typo or two:

```
<?php

$host="****";
$user="****";
$password="****";

$cxn = mysql_pconnect ($host, $user, $password);

mysql_select_db("defaultdb", $cxn);

if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) {
$ipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
} else {
$ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
}

$message = nl2br(strip_tags(nl2br($_POST["message"])));
if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) { 
if ($message != "") {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ChatTest (ID, TimeStamp, Message) VALUES ('$ipaddress', NOW(), '$message')");
}
header('Location: chat.php');
}

$message = "";

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ChatTest ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 

$tbl = '';
$tbl .= "<table border cellpadding=3 width='100%' style='table-layout:fixed'>
"; 
$tbl .= "<tr>"; 
$tbl .= "<th style='width:10%;'>ID:</th><th style='width:10%;'>TimeStamp:</th><th style='width:70%;'>Message:</th>";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
$tbl .= "
<tr>"; 
$tbl .= " <td>".$info['ID'] . "</td> "; 
$tbl .= " <td>".$info['TimeStamp'] . " </td>";
$tbl .= " <td style='white-space:pre-wrap;white-space:-moz-pre-wrap;white-space:-pre-wrap;white-space:-o-pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word'>".$info['Message'] . "</td></tr>
"; 
} 
$tbl .= "</table>"; 

mysql_close($cxn);

if (isset ($_GET['update']))
{
    echo $tbl;
    die ();
}

?>
<html><head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head><body><center>
<form action="chat.php" method="post">
Message: <br><textarea type="text" name="message" style="width:80%; height:300px;"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton"/> <a href="http://www.****.com/chat.php"><button name="Refresh Chat">Refresh Chat</button></a>
</form>
<div id="messages" style="width:100%;">
  <?php echo $tbl; ?>
</div></center>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function () {
    var updater = setTimeout (function () {
        $('div#messages').load ('chat.php', 'update=true');
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

As for coding techniques, you might want to look into SQL-injections and maybe writing cleaner HTML, but I'm sure you'll get there :)

Comment: Yes, exactly :) I will look that up in the mean time, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the only way you would do it without javascript is to use an iframe for the chat interface, and a meta refresh.

but why not use javascript?

Comment: by the way, look up "sql injection"... your chat script has a hole.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion haha, I have no problem using JavaScript... I just don't want to use Javascript that will reload the whole page... I just want to reload the table data and keep everything else on the page where it is (e.g. streaming videos, text boxes with text in them, progress bars, timers, etc.)

Comment: you don't need to reload the whole page. use Ajax to load just the chat data and refresh the interface.

Comment: Will this fix the SQL injection?
mysql_real_escape_string(